# Why does this SQL query take forever?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I tried running this query but it hangs the mysql server. It hits approximately 5 million records. Even the explain query does not return anything in time.

```
Explain SELECT COUNT(*)   FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Oms_Cart_Id )  Carts,Buyer_Id  
 FROM  Reporting.Order_Details  WHERE Buyer_Id  IN
    ( SELECT Buyer_Id
    FROM Reporting.Order_Details 
    WHERE Payment_Receive_Date>='2015-01-18 00:00:00' AND  
    Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY  Buyer_Id )  
 AND Payment_Receive_Date>='2014-09-01 00:00:00'   
 AND  Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY 2) X
 WHERE Carts>1
 LIMIT 0, 1000 ;
```

Comment: And the explain output is? Where did you add indexes?

Comment: @juergend index is on `Oms_Cart_Id ` & `Buyer_Id`. As I mentioned even the Explain query hangs the server never returns any result. Entire system goes down.

Comment: Always IN Query will make you slower. So better use Joins. Also use BETWEEN for Payment_Receive_Date instead of >=  and <=

Comment: This query hurts my brain. Why so much nesting and grouping for just a COUNT? And this question isn't possible for us to answer without more information.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Count how many buyers from one period have more than one cart from a larger period?

Comment: You mix a lot of expressions and functionality in a way that makes no sense. You can remove lots of things, like the innermost GROUP BY, move the carts into the sub-query HAVING clause. Remove LIMIT.

Comment: Also, you might find useful an index such as `CREATE INDEX DetailsNdx ON Order_Details(Payment_Receive_Date, Buyer_Id, Oms_Cart_Id);` to use with `BETWEEN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Yeah, brain hurt)

1. Get rid of useless LIMIT, only one row will be returned.
2. Turn the outer WHERE into an inner HAVING (for no good reason)
3. Turn the IN ( SELECT ... ) into a JOIN.  I started to do a self-join, but the GROUP BY said that perhaps that subquery is delivering only a few Buyer_Ids.  So, instead I did JOIN ( SELECT ... )

Result:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT a.Oms_Cart_Id ) Carts,
                a.Buyer_Id
            FROM  Reporting.Order_Details a
            JOIN  
              ( SELECT  Buyer_Id
                    FROM  Reporting.Order_Details
                    WHERE  Payment_Receive_Date>='2015-01-18 00:00:00'
                      AND  Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
                    GROUP BY  Buyer_Id
              ) AS b USING(Buyer_Id)
            WHERE  a.Payment_Receive_Date>='2014-09-01 00:00:00'
              AND  a.Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
            GROUP BY  2
            HAVING  Carts > 1 
      ) X ;
```

`Order_Details` would benefit from *both* of these:

`INDEX(Buyer_Id)`  -- for the JOIN.  (If you already have an index *starting* with `Buyer_Id`, don't add this one.)

`INDEX(Payment_Receive_Date, Buyer_Id)`  -- for the subsubquery

Perhaps that can be further simplified, if you really are doing just a COUNT(*):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT Buyer_Id)
    FROM  Reporting.Order_Details a
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  Buyer_Id
            FROM  Reporting.Order_Details
            WHERE  Payment_Receive_Date>='2015-01-18 00:00:00'
              AND  Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
            GROUP BY  Buyer_Id
      ) AS b USING(Buyer_Id)
    WHERE  Payment_Receive_Date>='2014-09-01 00:00:00'
      AND  Payment_Receive_Date<='2015-01-24 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY  2
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.Oms_Cart_Id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have shown us should be "hitting" around 4 rows, unless reporting.order_details is a federated table. Assuming that's not the the case, either your query is being blocked by something else or there is something very wrong with your server. Mysqladmin process list will tell you if the former is the case. Your system logs should show any issues with your disk. If neither are the case then your data files may be corrupt.